# Using std::unique_ptr on Object whose Size is Determined at Run Time

Tags: c++, stl, std, unique-ptr

I have the following code:

```
Gdiplus::Image image(filename.c_str());
UINT size = image.GetPropertyItemSize(PropertyTagExifDTOrig);
Gdiplus::PropertyItem* propertyItem = (Gdiplus::PropertyItem*)malloc(size);
```

The problem is that the code after this branches based on several different conditions. So I'd like to use something like `std::unique_ptr` to ensure the pointer on the last line gets deleted, no matter where my code branches.

However, it doesn't appear that `std::unique_ptr` can easily be implemented here. It seems to require a fixed-size type, and doesn't support a custom size.

Is this right? Is there any good way to implement an automatic pointer here?

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` when the code is C++?

Comment: @EdHeal: Kinda curious, is there anything wrong with doing it?

Comment: @Mehrdad 1) new calls constructors. 2) It is able to implement a different memory allocation strategy 3) Avoids problems of using `free` and not calling `delete` on a pointer - hence leaving OS resources dangling. 4) Being consistent

Comment: @EdHeal: Because I didn't see a good way to do this without `malloc()`. `malloc()` works okay, but I'd be happy to use a clean technique without it if one was demonstrated.

Comment: @JonathanWood: @EdHeal is right to avoid `malloc` in C++, and if you're not sure about that, it's sorta a separate question. If you explain what you're trying to do, there may be alternatives.

Comment: @EdHeal: (1) You're wrong in that the C++ alternative to `malloc` is *not* `new`, though. It's `operator new(size_t)`, which also does *not* call constructors. (2) Huh? What is "it", and why does this matter? (3) Again, the C++ alternative has the the problem of calling `operator delete`; using `malloc` instead of `operator new` doesn't change anything. (4) Okay, sure, that's one reason I guess.

Comment: @EdHeal: I think you might have misunderstood that the goal of the OP here is likely to allocate space larger than that needed for the object itself. There is no way to achieve that with `new T`; you have to use `operator new` in conjunction with *placement `new`*. The OP simply replaced `operator new` with `malloc`, which is perfectly fine in terms of readability/correctness; it's only slightly unidiomatic.

Comment: @JesseBeder: I'm trying to implement the standard Windows technique for getting an image file property using [`Image::GetPropertyItemSize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535391(v=vs.85).aspx) to obtain the size of the actual data, as recommended by Microsoft. As I keep saying, I'm not married to using `malloc()` if a clean alternative can be demonstrated. But so far I don't see any reasonable alternative. So far, EdHeal seems more like the type who likes to show what others are doing wrong and not so much one to show a better way.

Comment: @Mehrdad 1) Do not understand the comment. 2) It is possible to implement better strategies for memory allocation in certain cases 3) I refer to (2) and also using `free` will not call the destructor i.e not closing files/sockets....

Comment: @EdHeal: What I'm saying is that there is nothing wrong with using `malloc` *to allocate memory* in C++. Of course, there is something wrong with using it to *construct a new object*, but that's not a problem with using `malloc` itself -- it's a problem of using the wrong function entirely. Switching to the C++ counterpart (which is `operator new`) wouldn't be any more correct, so it's wrong to say `malloc` is the problem.

Comment: @Mehrdad - In C++ world just use new/delete and then you do not have to scratch your head. Using malloc followed by delete/new followed by free can lead to problems. Just use new/delete when writing C++

Comment: @EdHeal: You're missing 100% of the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: @Mehrdad - I did not say using `malloc` is wrong. What I think is wrong using it in C++ programs because a programmer is human. Does he need to use free/delete on this pointer? The class may have its own version of `new` to save memory etc. Release other resources. Prevent dangling pointers... So just use new/delete to avoid this problem in the first place and also to avoid it in the future

Comment: @EdHeal: I don't know how this can be spelled out to you any clearer. `new` will not work here because the size of the object is not known until run time. I understand you prefer `new` and `delete` in C++ programs, but there's no reason to have a fetish about it. In the end, a developer should use what works. And you haven't presented any way to make this code work with `new`. So just let it go.

Comment: Seems like `std::vector` handles this well i.e. `new[size] ...`

Comment: @JonathanWood - Besides it would horrify you if you know my fetish - it involves play-do, rubber bands and a cycle pump!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` supports a custom deleter. Since you're allocating with `malloc`, you can use `free`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Gdiplus::PropertyItem, void (*)(void*)> propertyItem{
    (Gdiplus::PropertyItem*) std::malloc(size), &std::free};
```

If you prefer to avoid passing the deleter, you can create a struct that does the deletion for you:

```
struct FreeDeleter {
  void operator()(void* p) {
    std::free(p);
  }
};

std::unique_ptr<Gdiplus::PropertyItem, FreeDeleter> propertyItem{
    (Gdiplus::PropertyItem*) std::malloc(size)};
```

Comment: Please do not encourage usage of `malloc` in C++ code.

Comment: @EdHeal: If you see a good way to implement this without `malloc()`, please share.